# Multi threaded finite element assembly implementation

Tags: finite-element, parallel-computing

What is typically the best way to multi thread the assembly loop in a finite element code? Does anyone have experience with implementing this, that they can share? I can think of a couple of ways of doing it:

1. Divide the mesh into different cell sets, where the elements in each set does not share dofs, such that the threads can add element-stiffness-matrices to the global stiffness matrix directly (without worrying about them accessing the same data).
2. Divide the mesh into cell sets and create a separate global stiffness matrix for each thread, and then combine the stiffness-matrices at the end.
3. Dont divide into cellsets, but rather spawn a new thread/tasks for each cell (this can be good for load balancing, if some of the elements are more expensive than others, while some are still elastic).

Comment: Option 4: don't overthink it. use a thread-safe container to add your sparse matrix triplets  in a parallel loop, in whatever order you please. that got my assembly time down to less than 1% of the total runtime. revisit the issue if it becomes a bottleneck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that I have just the right paper for you on this subject: [https://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/publications/2013-pattern.pdf](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Ebangerth/publications/2013-pattern.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely read it. Can you summarise what the best approach was?

Comment: If I understood everything correctly, I think that my option 1 was what gave best scalability in your paper. You use some sort of coloring algorithm such that you avoid the need for reduction.

Comment: @iljas No :-) That's what abstract, introduction, and conclusions of the paper are there for :-)

Comment: And yes, coloring is what makes it all work.